# How to convert $\ max \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx =\ min \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) dx $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, improper-integrals, functional-equations

Let $f$ or $g$ have a given condition.
( example $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f(x) exp(-x^2) dx = 1$ Or $g(g(x)) = x^3$  Or a differential equation for one of $f,g$. ) I want to find a general way - if possible - to get from $f$ to $g$ or vice versa :

$$ \max \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx = \min \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) dx $$

Where both sides converge , and a given condition for the other ( if the condition was for $f$ , then we get one for $g$. Or vice versa ).

I considered Cauchy-Schwartz , contour-integration and substitution but without succes.

How to handle this ?

Comment: It would really help if you gave an explicit example. $\max \int f(x)dx$ is meaningless, unless you mean $\max_{f\in F}$, for some set of functions $F$, in which case, your language implying you are talking about individual $f,g$ is confusing. If this is the intent of the question, I doubt that there are uniform techniues for solving such a problem.

Comment: Yes and the set of functions is the condition. Im not good with Tex sorry. @Thomas Andrews   +1